# How to tell if an edited photo has too much exposure?

Tags: exposure, photo-editing, brightness

Small sensor cameras produce photos that are dark. To fix this many increase exposure in their software editor. However, this fix can be quickly abused to the point of over-exposure, especially if the monitor's gamma level is abnormally high.

Underexposure is easy to spot. How about over-exposure? Are there technical or qualitative indicators of a photo being over-exposed?

Answer (score 2):

One possible indicator for over and under-exporuse is to have areas in the photo which are totally white or black. This mean there is not information about any details in these areas.

Most of the software have in histogram indicators about clipping in highlights or shadows:
[image]

Comment: What is being measured along the y-axis? And what value of that unit of measurement is considered clipping?

Comment: The y-axis represents the number count or percentage of occurrences in the data for each column. More interesting is X axis, if something go on the left or right outside you have clipping.